# chrome.storage save only changed data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension and I'm both saving and restoring data with chrome.storage.

Since there is more than one data, every time I need to save data, I re-save all the data. How do I get the data needed to be saved instead?

**How do I need to update the function?**

```
function setStorage() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"theme_color": $id("input_theme_color").value}, function() {
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({"history_content": historyContent}, function() {
    });
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"settings_update": lastSettingsUpdate}, function() {
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({"last_history_clear": lastHistoryClear}, function() {
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({"total_history_content": totalHistoryContent}, function() {
    });
    chrome.storage.local.set({"last_music": lastMusic}, function() {
    });
}
```

Comment: You'll have to read the storage first, then compare the data. If you data is small, you don't need this complication. BTW you can save all values in one call by merging all the key:value pairs into one object.

Comment: I don't think the data will ever exceed 500 kilobytes.

But the solution was to add switch-case to the function at first to me. (example: `setStorage("set-historyContent");` )
Do you think this makes sense?

Comment: Assuming this is the options page, you can keep the original value in a variable and then compare the edited value with that to see if it's changed. I don't understand what the problem is, everything seems straightforward to me.